# How to write and view converted pdfs to and from memory?

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine, ghostscript.net

Right now I am using ghostscript in Unity to convert pdfs to jpgs and view them in my project.

Currently it flows like so:
-Pdfs are converted into multiple jpegs (one for each page)
-The converted jpegs are written to disk
-They are then read in by bytes into a 2D texture
-And this 2D texture is assigned to a GameObjects RawImage component

This works perfectly in Unity, but... (now comes the hiccup) my project is intended to run on the Microsoft Hololens.
The Hololens runs on the Windows 10 API, but in a limited capacity.

Where the issue arises is when **I** try to convert pdfs and view them on the Hololens. Quite simply, the Hololens cannot create or delete files outside of its known folders (Pictures, Documents, etc).

My imagined solution to this problem is to instead of write the converted jpeg files to disk, write them to memory and view them from there.

In talking with GhostScript devs, I was told GhostScript.NET does what I am looking to do - convert pdfs and view them from memory (It does this with the Rasterizer/Viewer classes, I believe, but again I don't understand it quite well).

I've been lead to look at the latest GhostScript.NET docs to route out how this is done, but I simply don't understand them well enough to approach this.

My question is then, based on how I'm using ghostscript now, how do I use GhostScript.NET in my project to write the converted jpegs into memory and view them there?

Here's how I'm doing it now (code-wise):

```
        //instantiate
        byte[] fileData;
        Texture2D tex = null;

        //if a PDF file exists at the current head path
        if (File.Exists(CurrentHeadPath))
        {
            //Transform pdf to jpg
            PdfToImage.PDFConvert pp = new PDFConvert();
            pp.OutputFormat = "jpeg"; //format
            pp.JPEGQuality = 100; //100% quality
            pp.ResolutionX = 300; //dpi
            pp.ResolutionY = 500;
            pp.OutputToMultipleFile = true;
            CurrentPDFPath = "Data/myFiles/pdfconvimg.jpg";

            //this call is what actually converts the pdf to jpeg files
            pp.Convert(CurrentHeadPath, CurrentPDFPath);

            //this just loads the first image
            if (File.Exists("Data/myFiles/pdfconvimg" + 1 + ".jpg"))
            {
                //reads in the jpeg file by bytes
                fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("Data/myFiles/pdfconvimg" + 1 + ".jpg");
                tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
                tex.LoadImage(fileData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions.

                //Read Texture into RawImage component
                PdfObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = tex;
                PdfObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(288, 400);
                PdfObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().enabled = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Debug.Log("reached eof");
            }
        }
```

The convert function is from a script called [PDFConvert](https://pastebin.com/92uJ7pdk) which I obtained from code project. Specifically [How To Convert PDF to Image Using Ghostscript API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API).

Comment: @Programmer Updated grammar. But please, see "I've been lead to look at the latest GhostScript.NET docs to route out how this is done, but I simply don't understand them well enough to approach this.". I tried reading through the documentation and I do have a working implementation, but I'm looking for assistance in either changing it, or updating it to work on the Hololens platform. It is possible, so I updated the grammar.

Comment: You want to get help without telling us your problem? Run the code in your question then tell us if there is an issue. It's simply as that.

Comment: @Programmer "You want to get help without telling us your problem? Run the code in your question then tell us if there is an issue." I specify, "WHEN TRYING TO CONVERT PDFS AND VIEW THEM ON HOLOLENS..." denoting that I have indeed tried, and that it does not work. "HERE'S HOW I'M DOING IT NOW" implies that I am running code now, and here is how I am doing it. You either aren't present, reading clearly, or lack understanding in this subject matter. I am asking for help, I don't know how to save the images to memory. The hope is Josip sees this and is able to help. EDIT: Updated op for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

From the [GhostScript.Net documentation](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/documentation), take a look at the example code  labeled: "Using GhostscriptRasterizer class".  Specifically the following lines:

```
Image img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

The [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) class seems to be part of the [System.Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx) package, and System.Drawing.Image has another [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) method where the first parameter is a [System.IO.Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Does the Image.Save() method display/render a page to the screen?

Comment: The _rasterizer.GetPage() renders the PDF page to the Image Object. The Image.Save method saves it out in your specified format (e.g. ImageFormat.Png or ImageFormat.Jpeg) either to a file as in the code above or a stream.

Comment: Tried using Ghostscript.NET on the Hololens and ran into a laundry list of errors. Have decided to go another way. Thanks.